# Какой тип данных в SQL создавать?

Tags: java

У меня есть @Entity класс "Account".
Также, у меня есть @Entity класс "Transaction", который содержит 2 поля :

```
private Account from;
private Account to;
```

Такой вопрос : В самой таблице MYSQL какой тип данных указывать для "from" и "to" ?

Comment: Абсолютно такой же, как и у референсного поля (за исключением автоинкремента, если он там имеется). А то не срастётся.

Comment: Лучше всего никакой не указывать, пусть ORM сам об этом позаботится.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Так оно не дает создать таблицу без указания поля( при создании через IDEA)

Comment: @ТатьянаСергеева это странно, ведь половина смысла ORM в том, чтобы программисту не использовать SQL и вообще не лазить в БД.

Comment: @ТатьянаСергеева над полями укажите связь которая вам нужна - Одна к одному, многие к одному и т.д. И тогда ОРМ поймет что вы от него хотите.

Comment: Я так понял, что у вас 1-1 связь. В этом случае связь в бд осуществляется через REFERENCES. У вас должен быть ID в account и foreign key account_id в transaction который references на id в account. Так вот, указывайте такой тип, который у вас у ID в ACCOUNT. 
P.S. Все названия на английском относятся к бд, а не к яве(может возникнуть путаница из-за того что я писал и капсом и строчными)

Comment: @AntonSorokin связь, скорее всего, один-ко-многим. Аккаунт ведь может участвовать в разных (многих) транзакциях

Comment: @ОлексійМоренець вполне может быть

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос решен.

Автоматически направляю данные в базу с помощью JPA - HIBERHATE.

Answer (score 0):

java:

```
    private String Account from;
    private String Account to;
```

mysql:

```
    from NVARCHAR(20),
    to NVARCHAR(20)
```

Comment: Что это такое `private String Account from;`? Компилятор на такое будет ругаться